# How to do forward / back navigation in VSCode but disregard manual cursor (eg: up/down) motion?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode, is there a way to disregard cursor motion in the code navigation history? That is, when I jump into a definition, I usually move the cursor a bit (eg: up/down) to inspect the surrounding code. When I issue the "navigate back" command, it incorporates the cursor movement into the navigation history stream. That is, navigating back will just move up/down one line. I almost always want to disregard manual cursor movement when navigating code. The JetBrains IntelliJ suite of tools behaves this way. Can VSCode be configured to do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be a conflict with VSCode/VIM causing this behavior. VSCode/VIM affects the code navigation history it looks like, injecting cursor movements into the command stream so that VSCode's native "Go Back" traverses the cursor movement stream, which is generally undesirable.

The VIM jump list behaves correctly though so I've switched to using ctrl+o and ctrl+i to navigate back/forward.